# What Is This Dart Method Called?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I figure this must be a pretty common method in Dart. I couldn't find it anywhere, so I created my own. It adds the contents of an arbitrary number of `Iterable<T>`s together. I called it `aggregate`

```
extension IterableExtensions<T> on Iterable<Iterable<T>> {
  List<T> aggregate() {
    final list = <T>[];
    forEach((element) {
      element.forEach(list.add);
    });
    return list;
  }
}
```

Does this method exist in another library? If so, what is the method called and what do I import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve the problem of flattening an iterable in two ways:

Either

1. Import dart expansion pack for collection API and use `flattened`:
   https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableIterableExtension.html

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

// [...]

iterable.flattened.toList();
```

2. Use `expand` (aka `flatMap` in other languages) method on the outer iterable

```dart
iterable.expand((nested) => nested).toList();
```

https://pub.dev/packages/collection

Comment: I didn't know about the `flattened` extension method. (Alas, extension methods seem hard to find in dartdocs if you aren't specifically looking for them.)  Good find!

Answer (score 2):

I'd just call it flattening a list.  A simpler way to do it is:

```dart
List<T> flatten<T>(Iterable<Iterable<T>> iterables) =>
    [for (var iterable in iterables) ...iterable];
```

[`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) provides [`CombinedIterableView`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/CombinedIterableView-class.html) and [`CombinedListView`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/CombinedListView-class.html) classes that do the same thing but lazily.  It also provides an [`IterableZip`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableZip-class.html) class that is similar but iterates over items in a breadth-first manner instead of depth-first.

[`package:quiver`](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) also provides [`concat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.iterables/concat.html) and [`zip`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.iterables/zip.html) functions.